# How is a set of the form $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook "Introduction to Set Theory" mentions the following set $$\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$ This confuses me. Is it possible that $\emptyset$ be an element of a set? I thought only sets of the form $\{\{\dots\{\emptyset\}\dots\}\}$ were allowed to be elements of other sets.

By what I've understood until now, $\emptyset$ is not a member of the set $\{a,b,c\}$, but **is** a member of $\{\emptyset,a,b,c\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. For any set $A$ you have the set $\{A\}$.

Comment: yes, $\emptyset $ may be an element of another set. And yes, your last assertion is correct (assuming that none of $a,b,c$ is $\emptyset$).

Comment: You can construct $\mathbb{N}$ this way: $0=\{\emptyset\}$, $1=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, and so on.

Comment: @Siminore: No, $0=\varnothing$, not $\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can also start with $\left\{\emptyset,\left\{\emptyset\right\}\right\}$ and adjust your addition. :P

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

- Set $\{\varnothing\}$, sometimes written as $\{\{\}\}$ is "an empty box in a box".
- In this wording $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ is a box that contains two boxes, one empty, while the second contains yet another empty box.
- Yes, you are correct. We have $\varnothing \notin \{a,b,c\}$, still $\varnothing \subset \{a,b,c\}$. Also, $\varnothing \in \{\varnothing,a,b,c\}$ and of course $\varnothing \subset \{\varnothing,a,b,c\}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: (+1) for “*an empty box in a box*”

Answer (score 2):

"Pretty much" every mathematical object can be an element of a set. And the whole point behind the idea of sets is to have collections of mathematical objects as mathematical objects. So sets can be elements of other sets as well. $\varnothing$ is a set, so it can be an element of other sets.

The set $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ has two elements, $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ (which itself has one element).